# How to randomize every character from different user inputs

Tags: python

New to coding, and I have a problem for generating a password. I want to randomize the users input at the end when all the input has been done already.

Here is my code:

```
# Imports
import random
import string

# My function to generate lower cases as much as the user want to
def lower_cases():
   global result_1
   user_1 = int(input("How many lower cases do you want in your password? "))
   chars_small = string.ascii_lowercase
   result_1 = ''.join(random.choice(chars_small) for i in range (user_1))

# My function to generate upper cases as much as the user want to
def upper_cases():
   global result_2
   user_2 = int(input("How many upper cases do you want in your password? "))
   chars_upper = string.ascii_uppercase
   result_2 = ''.join(random.choice(chars_upper) for i in range(user_2))

# My function to generate digits as much as the user want to
def characters():
   global result_3
   user_3 = int(input("How many digits do you want in your password? "))
   digits = string.digits
   result_3 = ''.join(random.choice(digits) for i in range(user_3))

# My main fucntion where all the other functions are
def main():
   lower_cases()
   upper_cases()
   characters()

   print(result_1 + result_2 + result_3)

   print("\n")

   # Asking the user if he want to end it here or want to go again
   restart = input("Do you want to start again? if so type 'yes' else type 'no' ").lower()
   if restart == "yes":
      print('\n'*80)
      main()
   else:
      exit()

 if __name__ == '__main__':  # code to execute if called from command-line
    main()
```

and this is my output:

```
How many lower cases do you want in your password? 4
How many upper cases do you want in your password? 3
How many digits do you want in your password? 4
gxmcVQK9888
```

My problem is that I want to randomize this password and not first the lower cases then the upper cases etc...

Comment: Also, why are you using `global`s instead of returning from the functions?

Comment: Also, instead of doing `random.choice(l) for i in range(n)` you can just do `random.choices(l, k=n)`